# Not able to install kmodes in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am not able to install kmodes using `pip install kmodes` while doing this I am getting
[this warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqw0c.png)

Comment: Please, copy-paste the text of the warning directly in your question rather than using a screenshot of the warning.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a warning, it just lists what is happening when the package kmodes is being installed. And from that image, it is clear that you have some packages required for kmodes. However, you have `scikit-learn 0.18.1` but kmodes requires another version of it, so it is attempting to uninstall this existing version.